# Looping through the children of parent containers

Tags: javascript

I have 2 groups of parent containers, both with 5 children each -- 4 paragraphs and 2 buttons per container.

When the button in each container is clicked, a class is added to the paragraph element, one at a time. After the last paragraph child element is reached, the first paragraph child gets the class added to it again.

Below are the code. When the last paragraph is reached, I want the class added immediately to the first paragraph -- but the counter won't reset. 
If you check the console.log, both counter and j go to 4, which it shouldnt. After both counter and j reaches 3, it should reset back to 0. My parameters are probably way off.

```js
var container = document.querySelectorAll(".container");
var button = document.querySelectorAll("button");
var p = document.querySelectorAll("p");

var click = function(i) {
  var counter = -1;
  button[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    counter++;
    console.log(counter);

    for (j = 0; j < p.length / 2 + 1; j++) {
      console.log(i, j);
      this.parentNode.children[j].classList.remove("active");
      if (j === counter) {
        this.parentNode.children[j].classList.add("active");
      }
      if (counter === p.length / 2) {
        counter = -1;
      }
    }
  });
}

for (i = 0; i < button.length; i++) {
  click(i);
}
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p>Test1</p>
  <p>Test2</p>
  <p>Test3</p>
  <p>Test4</p>
  <button>click</button>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <p>Test1</p>
  <p>Test2</p>
  <p>Test3</p>
  <p>Test4</p>
  <button>click</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's enough to add a modulus 4 op immediately after the increment:

```
counter %= 4;
```

Because the number of paragraphs may change you can compute their number on the fly:

```
var maxParagrapgh = button[i].parentNode.querySelectorAll('p').length;
```

And so the increment is:

```
counter = (counter + 1) % maxParagrapgh;
```

The running snippet:

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(e) {
    var container = document.querySelectorAll(".container");
    var button = document.querySelectorAll("button");
    var p = document.querySelectorAll("p");

    var click = function(i){
        var counter = -1;
        var maxParagrapgh = button[i].parentNode.querySelectorAll('p').length;
        button[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
            counter = (counter + 1) % maxParagrapgh;
            // console.log(counter);

            for(j=0;j<p.length/2+1;j++){
                // console.log(i, j);
                this.parentNode.children[j].classList.remove("active");
                if(j === counter){
                    this.parentNode.children[j].classList.add("active");
                }
                if(counter === p.length/2){
                    counter = -1;
                }
            }
        });
    }

    for(i=0;i<button.length;i++){
        click(i);
    }
})
```

```css
.active {
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <p>Test1</p>
    <p>Test2</p>
    <p>Test3</p>
    <p>Test4</p>
    <button>click</button>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <p>Test1</p>
    <p>Test2</p>
    <p>Test3</p>
    <p>Test4</p>
    <button>click</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. Your solution would never have crossed my mind.

Comment: this is a revelation... i never knew you can querySelector(All) inside a parentNode... amazing... plus using the modulus to handle variable lengths... thank you